# swiftui binding use any type and convert use as?

Tags: swiftui

i has a protocol and some struct

```
public protocol BlockContent_P {
    var type:Int { get }
}
// structs
public struct Block<BlockContent_P> {
    public var content: BlockContent_P
 }
public struct MarkdownContent: BlockContent_P{
    public var rawContent: String = ""
}
```

i want binding a property and create a String Binding:

```
@Binding var block: Block<any BlockContent_P>

let e = Binding<String>.init {
    (block.content as? MarkdownContent)?.rawContent ?? ""
} set: { v in
    (block.content as? MarkdownContent)?.rawContent = v
}
```

but, is not work, has a error: `Cannot assign to immutable expression of type 'String'`
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8h3KB.png)

swiftui binding is not support Optional type？

I added the complete test code, please copy this code completely into the contentview file in the newly created empty swiftUI.

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  Test
//
//  Created by xx on 2022/12/28.
//

import SwiftUI


protocol BlockContent_P {
    var type: Int {get}
}

struct Block<BlockContent_P> {
    var content: BlockContent_P
}

struct MarkdownContent:BlockContent_P {
    var rawContent: String = ""
    var type: Int {
        return 0
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var block: Block <any BlockContent_P> = Block<BlockContent_P>.init(content: MarkdownContent.init())
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            Text("Hello, world!")
            Markdown(text: Binding<String>.init(get: {
                (block.content as? MarkdownContent)?.rawContent ?? ""
            }, set: { v in
                (block.content as? MarkdownContent)?.rawContent = v
            }))
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct Markdown: View {
    @Binding var text: String
    var body: some View {
        Text(text)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

`expectation`:
Binding convert success

Comment: Could you please post enough code so that it compiles.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson : i think that is the problem : it does not compile.

Comment: Your struct MarkdownContent does not implement the protocol BlockContent_P.

Comment: @PtitXav yes I worded that incorrectly, I meant enough code to reproduce because I get a completely different compilation error.

Comment: Your main problem is that you add a setter to a constant (let). That is contradictory.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson,hi, I added the complete test code,Hope this helps you reproduce,thinks

Comment: @PtitXav hi, Do you know if it is used Binding<any Protocol> in swiftui

Answer (score 0):

May be try to replace your setter :

```
        Markdown(text: Binding<String>.init(get: {
            (block.content as? MarkdownContent)?.rawContent ?? ""
        }, set: { v in
            // this seems to lead to really contents
            // (block.content as? MarkdownContent)?.rawContent = v
            // get the contents as markdownContent  and update it
            if var markdownContent = block.content as? MarkdownContent {
                markdownContent.rawContent = v
                block.content = markdownContent
            }
        }))
```

You can also simplify the declaration :

```
@State var block: Block <any BlockContent_P> = Block(content: MarkdownContent())
```